# Redondear decimal en c# siempre al numero mayor

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de redondear un numero decimal, pero lo que sucede normalmente es que si el numero es suponiendo `40.40` se queda en `40`, y si es `40.60` sube a `41` mi código es el siguiente:

```
decimal price = 13224.60m;
int aux = (int) Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(price), 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

así como esta el código si lo ejecuto me da como resultado `13225`, pero si cambio el valor de `price` a `13224.40`:

```
decimal price = 13224.40m;
int aux = (int) Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(price), 0, MidpointRounding.ToEven);
```

me da como resultado `13224`, y lo que yo quiero es que siempre me lo redondee hacia arriba es decir, que en cualquiera de los dos casos me lo redondee a `13225`.

¿hay alguna forma de hacer eso ? y si la hay, ¿como seria la implementación?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes utilizar:

```
decimal price = Math.Ceiling(13224.40m);
```

Answer (score 4):

Hay dos metodos en c# el primero  `Math.Ceiling(decimal)` que redondea el valor ingresado a su numero entero **mayor** inmediato, y tambien `Math.Floor(decimal)` que redondea el valor ingresado a su numero entero **menor** inmediato, ve estor ejemplos:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0,7} {1,16} {2,14}", 
                     value, Math.Ceiling(value), Math.Floor(value));

//         Value          Ceiling          Floor
//       
//          7.03                8              7
//          7.64                8              7
//          0.12                1              0
//         -0.12                0             -1
//          -7.1               -7             -8
//          -7.6               -7             -8
```